# Check if item is found in text file

Tags: c#, duplicates, streamwriter

How can I check if a text file contains an item from a listbox. To stop saving duplicates. I'm not sure what I'd add to this. This is called on a button click event. For example, if a duplicate was found, I could show `MessageBox.Show ("duplicate error");`

```
 using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("test.txt", true))
        {
            foreach (object item in listBox2.Items)
            {
                writer.WriteLine(item.ToString());
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before writing to "test.txt", enumerate its contents:

```
var fileLines = File.ReadAllLines("test.txt");
List<string> fileItems = new List<string>(fileLines);
```

Then before you write each item, check to see if the list contains it:

```
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("test.txt", true))
{
    foreach (object item in listBox2.Items)
    {
        if (fileItems.Contains(item))
            // Do something, break, etc.
        else
            writer.WriteLine(item.ToString());
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

Per suggestions, you can use a `HashSet` instead of a `List` for performance, as it can only contain unique values.

Another improvement may be to check if any duplicates exist before writing anything to the file. I've done that in the example below in a LINQ statement:

```
var fileLines = File.ReadAllLines("test.txt");
HashSet<string> fileItems = new HashSet<string>(fileLines);

using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("test.txt", true))
{
    bool duplicateFound = fileItems.Any(fi => listBox1.Items.Cast<string>().Any(i => i == fi));

    if (duplicateFound)
        MessageBox.Show("Duplicate items found.");
    else
        foreach (object item in listBox1.Items)
            writer.WriteLine(item.ToString());
}
```

**Edit 2:**

As @Servy suggested, the listbox could contain duplicates, which should also be taken into consideration. Additionally, my HashSet implementation was sub-par. So in this third example, I am first checking if the listbox contains duplicates, then if any of the listbox items are already in the file. The usage of HashSet is more performant as well because I am not iterating it.

```
var fileLines = File.ReadAllLines("test.txt");
HashSet<string> fileItems = new HashSet<string>(fileLines);
List<string> duplicateListboxItems = listBox1.Items.Cast<string>().GroupBy(l => l).Where(g => g.Count() > 1).Select(g => g.Key).ToList();
if (duplicateListboxItems.Count > 0)
{
    MessageBox.Show("The listbox contains duplicate entries.");
    return;
}

bool duplicateFound = false;
List<string> outputItems = new List<string>();
foreach (string item in listBox1.Items)
{
    if (fileItems.Contains(item))
    {
        MessageBox.Show(String.Format("The file has a duplicate: {0}", item));
        duplicateFound = true;
        break;
    }
    outputItems.Add(item);
}

if (duplicateFound)
    return;

using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("test.txt", true))
{
    foreach (string s in outputItems)
        writer.WriteLine(s);
}
```

Comment: You could change `fileItems` to a `HashSet<string>` and this would run substantially faster.  You wouldn't need to change *anything* else.  You also need to add the items from the listbox to `fileItems` in your `foreach`.

Comment: actually, if you change to HashSet, it becomes even easier, because you don't need to check for contains and add will return true/false in case it already exists and it was not added

Comment: @Alex Yep, modified my answer to do that because it's just so clean.

Comment: You still aren't catching any duplicate items in the listbox itself.  Your use of the `hashSet` is also...terrible.  You completely defeat the purpose of using a hashset when you iterate over that set and then for each item, iterate the entire listbox.  You should go through each listbox item and see if the hashset contains it.  That will *dramatically* improve performance.  As I said, just use your first code sample and just change the type of `fileItems` to `HashSet`, no more, no less, and you'll dramatically improve performance.

Comment: @Servy I was assuming the listbox would not contain duplicates, but you're correct it should not be assumed. I'll do a third edit to reflect that but then we're converging on the same answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
string filePath = "test.txt";
var existingLines = new HashSet<string>(File.ReadAllLines(filePath));

var linesToWrite = new List<string>();
foreach (string item in listBox2.Items)
{
    if (existingLines.Add(item))
    {
        linesToWrite.Add(item);
    }
    else
    {
        //this is a duplicate!!!
    }
}

File.AppendAllLines(filePath, linesToWrite);
```

Comment: How would I fit this into my code? Sorry i'm still learning to code

Comment: @user1353517 This effectively replaces all of it.  It reads all of the lines of the file, combines them with all of the lines in your listbox, removes all duplicates, and then writes all of the data back out to the file.